# Long equation design patterns in LaTeX

Tags: equations

Is there an acceptable design pattern for how to type out LaTeX math formulas that have a lot of internal dependencies (the formulas do not necessarily have to be very long, just be very packed variables-wise).  For example, `y=xyz*\sqrt{t} where x=a, y=b, z=r, and t=q`.  This is a purely hypothetical equation but it's basically asking if we should use the word "where" in the same long equation or whether we should partition off separate equations in separate `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` environments and then reference back for each dependency. This second approach seems sort of unwieldy to me but, then again, the first approach is not great either (especially when for `x=a`, it turns out that `a` is some huge integral formula).

Maybe there is a better approach or perhaps even an accepted design pattern for how to deal with long and/or packed equations with many variables with long definitions?

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
Z=\nu\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{f(z)-g(z)}+\beta + \xi\frac{f(m)-g(m)}{f(n)-g(n)}+\theta 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously, there is no room to define variables like `\theta` in-line, even using the long equation LaTeX environment.  If I use the `split` environment, the equation will just look long and messy.

Hence, I'm wondering if there is a best practices approach I can follow to get the job done within the constraints that LaTeX offers for handling mathematical equations.

Comment: Is this on-topic? I seems more a question of how best to layout mathematics rather than an issue about implementation in TeX.

Comment: @cfr Good point.  But I think it's on topic b/c it's a question about what kind of layout or TeX style to use for long packed equations when typesetting them in LaTeX.  It sounds like a better question for here than for math.stackexchange b/c there is no explicit math content in this question.

Comment: This is also about mathematical grammar and usage.  Here is a discussion with a very good reference list in this 2010 question's answers http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14189/what-are-or-where-can-i-find-style-guidelines-for-writing-math/14196#14196

Comment: Question edited to demonstrate example equation in LaTeX, with the question of how to then define each and every dependency (e.g., \theta)...

Comment: Your question is very interesting, but it's really much more about mathematical writing principles and styles rather than how to, say, implement any given stylistic choice using the tools of TeX and friends. As such, I do think that it's off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Mico I am inclined to agree. But it could be construed as a 'best practice within the constraints TeX offers' type question, so it seems borderline to me.

Comment: I wonder if this would be a better fit for GraphicDesign.SE under their `typography` tag.

Comment: @cfr Question edited to incorporate your advice.  I also agree with what others are writing here but, at the same time, I'm looking for some TeX-centered advice (e.g., a package or way to use an environment to help me get the job done).

Comment: Just imagine someone is writing a math equation up in LaTeX and encounters this issue (which I'm sure is pretty common): are they more likely to find an answer on tex.stackexchange or math.stackexchange?  Hopefully, the title of the question will lead them here via a google search.  I think it's the most intuitive way to phrase the problem, at least on a first search.

Comment: @warship I voted to keep the question open because the only other option seems to me to be to split it i.e. to ask a question about how to layout the equations on the maths or design site and then to ask another about how to implement the solution in TeX here. But it is not clear to me that that is the best approach since what-can-be-reasonably-implemented seems to be a relevant consideration when thinking about how-this-can-best-be-implemented.

Comment: @SeanAllred -- i think that there is little expertise in the graphic design group regarding the presentation of math -- too specialized.  much better fit with the math.sx group, and the list given in the answer linked by r.schumacher is excellent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scanning through a book by someone who has thought a lot about mathematical typesetting, namely *The Art of Computer Programming*, I find nowhere a displayed equation followed by an inlined variable definition. At most, an equation is followed by a condition like "for real x>0".

Often Knuth introduces variables *before* the long equation: "Let θ be ... Then we find `<long equation>`".